# import csv file in Neo4j?

Tags: neo4j

I try to using Neo4j tool and import csv files.

and I have a problem.
my csv file is clear but, in neo4j browser.

LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///sample.csv' AS row
return row.

row.name is return strange characters like ������.

yeah, the ������ is not English.
what is the problem. and how to fix it?
thank you.

Answer (score 0):

look at the encoding of your .csv file if it's `UTF-8` and not `latin1` (`ISO-8859-1`)

Comment: thank you for reply.
save utf-8 and import again.
but, it failed too,. thank you

Comment: When you saved in utf-8, the conversion was also done? When I need to do something like that, I usually use the `Encoding->Convert to` of `notepad++`.

Comment: oh, notepad++ encoding is nice and clear.
you save me thank you very much!